# Replacing unencodable characters

Tags: python, string, unicode, decode, encode

Im currently working on something where i need to pull some `.xml` from a website and work with it.

Everything is working fine, but if i try to print the `.xml` (or text after parsing it) and there is some character in the `.xml` that cant be encoded, i get that error:

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)
[0]UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2665' in position 1161: character maps to <undefined>
```

Now i want to locate these characters and replace them with a "?" for example.

How do i do this?

Is there a better method for handling these errors?

Comment: Is that the full error stack?  Are you calling `codecs.charmap_encode` directly from your own code?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 by any chance? This is one of the areas where Python 3 brings significant relief.

Comment: The better method is to configure your Python so it can output the full Unicode range. I understand this is more challenging on Windows, but then that's one more reason to move off Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote the code that generated that error it would be easier to help you, in any case, usually, you can encode the string in `utf8` and then do the decoding:

```
data = '\u2665'
data = data.encode('utf8')
print(data)  # b'\xe2\x99\xa5'
data_d = data.decode('utf8')
print(data_d)  # ♥
```

Moreover you can add this line at the beginning of your script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and then verify the `stdout.encoding` with:

```
import sys
print(sys.stdout.encoding)
```